# Oozie shell action > why only some shell command is allow but not all

Tags: oozie

In the Oozie shell action, I tried to use the command `mkdir` directly, it worked. But when I tried other commands like `exec`. There is error ``command not found`. Why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $ which exec
>
> /usr/bin/which: no exec in
> (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/)
>
> $ man bash
>
> ... SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS
>
> ...    exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]

Duh! `exec` is not a Linux executable that you can find in the PATH; it is a *shell built-in command* -- just like `unset` or `alias` or `if .. then .. else .. fi`

But you *can* start a shell just to run `exec` i.e.

```
bash -c "echo 'IN SUB-PROCESS' ; exec echo 'this is really a complicated way to run ECHO and terminate' ; echo 'NOT EXECUTED, EXEC TERMINATED THE SUB-PROCESS'"
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your compact explanation. This is exactly what I would like to know. But continuously I would like to know why exec can still be called even though it is not a Linux executable? Is is embedded is the shell binary?

Comment: The shell runs a parser on the commands that you type, then it filters out the *built-in* commands for internal processing, and for the rest it tries to find a matching executable. That's what "built-in" means. And with `csh` shell you would have very different built-ins w/ different syntax, by the way.